# how to extend the DRBD device online on production server?

Tags: linux, drbd

Hey folks i am trying to extends the size of DRBD device (**/dev/drbd0**) online on production server but  have to bring down and up the device (**/dev/drbd0**) **twice** so the change in size is detected.

I just wanna know that is their any way to extend the size of **DRBD** device without Down and up the **DRBD** resource device. Actually i followed [this link](http://lists.linbit.com/pipermail/drbd-user/2008-September/010317.html).

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Sure there is. What is your drbd major/minor version, and what is your underlying storage device for drbd0?

Answer (score 2):

After the LV resize do a `drbdadm resize`.

1. Resize the LVs on both sides - I recommend using a relative size e.g. `lvresize -L +2G`
2. Resize DRBD while drbd is commected `drbdadm resize` - you see the progess in `cat /proc/drbd`
3. Resize the filesystem online